# Polynomial fit: removing outliers

Tags: regression, correlation, outliers, fitting, scatterplot

I want to **fit** a scatter plot with a polynomial, and find the **correlation** between two variables.

1) How can I define and **remove outliers** from data points? 
(in the figure the outliers on the right misled the polynomial fit, which didn't capture the linear relationship)

[image]

where SE is the squared error, R is the Pearson correlation coefficient, and $\rho$ is the Spearman Correlation Coefficient.

Comment: First I'd start by recommending thinking carefully about that datapoint and if you really should be removing it.  A far out point like this could indeed be a valid observation that you should take into account during your modeling process.  If that point is truly a mistake for some reason, then it's probably okay to simply remove as long as the process that led to the mistake isn't somehow related to your variables of interest.  Can you tell us more about your data and why you think this point should be removed as an "outlier?"

Comment: What linear relationship? Even upon removing many points at the right of this figure, the rest do not seem to be approximated well by any kind of line.

Answer (score -1):

In the picture, you posted, outlier is on the x axis. We can remove them using [IQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) and example code of doing it in R can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787332/how-to-remove-outliers-from-a-dataset)

Here is an example on simulated data for your case:left subfigure is the data without outlier, the right subfigure is the data with outlier. (I am manually adding 3 data points in `mtcars` data.)

As you can see, those 3 data points make the regression line flat.

[image]

Code

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
d=mtcars[,c("wt","mpg")]
plot(d)
fit=lm(mpg~wt,d)
summary(fit)
abline(fit)

d2=rbind(d,c(40,20),c(45,20),c(50,20))
plot(d2)
fit2=lm(mpg~wt,d2)
summary(fit2)
abline(fit2)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. What do you mean by "outlier is on the x axis" ? I think the outliers are those at around points (1.5, 14), (0.7, 12) and (1, 17).

Comment: no, the major problem is the 3 data points on the right side. I can give you a demo on a simulate data. if you want.

Comment: It would be great to see the demo, thanks. Do you mean that those three points do not affect correlation or the regression?

Comment: @CarloAlessi I am saying those 3 data points are culprit, and removing them should be your fix.

Comment: Would you please post either the raw data, or a link to the raw data?

Comment: I would strongly caution against blindly applying procedures like this that simply remove suspected outliers, based on some crude approach such as excluding those that fall outside of the IQR.